# SQL query: how to filter a many to many relationship

Tags: sql

I have ONE table, contains a clientID and a subclientID, how to filter this to retrun clients that contain BASE and 1 **ONLY**. In this case, I would like to return client 46

| clientID | subclientID |
| --- | --- |
| 44 | 1 |
| 44 | 9 |
| 44 | BASE |
| 44 | 2 |
| 45 | BASE |
| 45 | 2 |
| 46 | BASE |
| 46 | 1 |
| 46 | 1 |

EDIT: subclient may contains duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of finding that:

```
select clientid
from (
  select clientid,
    case when subclientid in ('BASE', '1') then 1 else 2 end as score
  from test
) x
group by clientid
having sum(score) = 2;
```

**Explanation**

```
  select clientid,
    case when subclientid in ('BASE', '1') then 1 else 2 end as score
  from test
```

will change `BASE` and `1` to the score 1. Everything else will be given score 2. The result will be like this:

> ```
> clientid |  score
> -------: | -----:
>       44 |  1
>       44 |  2
>       44 |  1
>       44 |  2
>       45 |  1
>       45 |  2
>       46 |  1
>       46 |  1
> ```

Then, for each clientid we sum up the score. If the score is exactly 2, we know we want that client id.

**Examples**

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1f845cfbb15657283c6758c186daf1c3
- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3984ebea44659fee444f1502ecd5ee61
- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3984ebea44659fee444f1502ecd5ee61

## Edit - if you have duplicates

If you have duplicates, you can use this:

```
select clientid
from (
  select clientid,
    case when subclientid in ('BASE', '1') then 1 else 2 end as score
  from (select distinct clientid, subclientid from test) t
) x
group by clientid
having sum(score) = 2;
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=29590e13e0603bc675167950da05114b

Comment: Good solution, but it can not deal with duplicates, I have edited the table

Comment: @Saddy I added an example of how you can still get the right answer even if you have duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is one option here:

```sql
SELECT clientID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY clientID
HAVING MIN(subclientID) <> MAX(subclientID) AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN subclientID NOT IN ('1', 'BASE') THEN 1 END) = 0;
```